# To solve $ \dfrac1m+\dfrac1n-\dfrac1{mn^2}=\dfrac34$

Tags: number-theory

How do we find all positive integers $(m,n)$ such that $ \dfrac1m+\dfrac1n-\dfrac1{mn^2}=\dfrac34$ ?

Comment: It reduces to the polynomial form $-3mn^2+4n^2+4mn-4=0$ if that's useful.

Comment: Note that you need $\frac 1m+\frac 1n\gt \frac 34$ which reduces the number of cases to a manageable number.

Answer (score 6):

Since this is equivalent to the integer equation $$4n^2+4mn-4=3mn^2$$ then $n$ must divide $4$. Similar to @MarkBennet's answer, there are only a small number of cases to check.

If $n=1$, then $4m=3m$, so this doesn't give any solutions.

If $n=2$, then $12+8m=12m$, and $m=3$.

If $n=4$, then $60+16m=48m$, which gives no solutions.

---

You can check for negative solutions too this way, but it turns out there are none:

If $n=-1$, then $-4m=3m$, so this doesn't give any solutions.

If $n=-2$, then $12-8m=12m$, which gives no solutions.

If $n=-4$, then $60-16m=48m$, which gives no solutions.

Comment: Yes, the left side is divisable with 4, so the right side need as well. But why means that n must divide 4? What is if only 4|m ?

Comment: @PeterHorvath Note that we can look at the equation as linear in $m$ so that $$m=\frac {4(n^2-1)}{3n^2-4n}$$

Now note that $\left(n, (n+1)(n-1)\right)=1$ (they have no non-trivial common factor), so if the expression is to be an integer we must have $n|4$.

Comment: @MarkBennet Thanks!

Comment: @PeterHorvath Also you can look at that equation as $n(4n+4m-3mn)=4$ after rearranging terms and factoring. $n$ divides the left side, so it must also divide the right side.

Answer (score 4):

Since you need $\frac 1m+\frac 1n\gt \frac 34$ you need either $\frac 1m\ge \frac 38\gt \frac 13$ or alternatively $\frac 1n \gt \frac 13$

The number of cases is small and they can be checked quickly.

---

To be more concrete about the cases involved, we must have either $m\leq 2$ or $n\leq 2$.

$m=1$ gives $\frac 1n-\frac 1{n^2}=-\frac 14$, or $4(n-1)=-n^2$which is impossible for positive integer $n$. Note that $n^2+4n-4=0$ has roots $n=-2\pm 2\sqrt 2$.

$m=2$ gives $\frac 1n-\frac 1{2n^2}=\frac 14$, which becomes $4n-2=n^2$ and this is impossible in integers since an even square is divisible by $4$. Also $n^2-4n+2=0$ has roots $n=2\pm \sqrt 2$

$n=1$ gives $\frac 1m+1-\frac 1m=\frac 34$ which is false.

$n=2$ gives $\frac 1m-\frac 1{4m}=\frac 14$ or $m=3$