# To solve $ \dfrac1m+\dfrac1n-\dfrac1{mn^2}=\dfrac34$ on all integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, diophantine-equations

Refering [To solve $ \dfrac1m+\dfrac1n-\dfrac1{mn^2}=\dfrac34$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786096/to-solve-dfrac1m-dfrac1n-dfrac1mn2-dfrac34) , I think it is an interesting question, if the possible solution are integers, thus

How do we find all integers $(m,n)$ such that $ \dfrac1m+\dfrac1n-\dfrac1{mn^2}=\dfrac34$?

Comment: So this question differs from that one in that you allow negative integer solutions? If so the solution I posted still applies, but you just have three more cases to check: $n\in\{-1,-2,-4\}$.

Comment: @alex.jordan Thanks! I accepted/upvoted that if I could.